# Freeform field data on success page

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm trying to display some user entered data on the success/thank you page.

From http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/10692/ I've got return="rsvp/success/%%entry_id%%" and when I submit the form I end up rsvp/success/49, rsvp/success/50, rsvp/success/51, etc.

On rsvp/success I have:

```
{exp:freeform:entries entry_id="{segment_3}"}
{if freeform:no_results}<h4>Sorry, no results were found.</h4>{/if}
<h4>{freeform:field:concert_date} / {freeform:field:concert_tickets} Guests</h4>
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

But I always get no results were found. I've tried adding dynamic="no". I've tried hard coding the entry_id. I've even tried search:FIELD_NAME and looking for something else in the entry. Always no results were found.

In a different area of the site, I've had use form_id and entry_id together to get a single entry. Does it always need both?

EE 2.7.2, Freeform Pro 4.1.3

Thanks
Amanda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the form_id parameter so freeform knows which table to lookin for hte entry_id.  Each form gets it's own table to store data in.

Comment: Too bad. My end game was just to search for a hash like in the last comment (http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/10692/#53672). I'll now have to pass the form_name (user selected in the entry), form_id (query based on form_name) and hash value from my template to Low Vars that displays the form.
Thanks @solspace for the info.